# Peak convolution

Tags: fitting

I am not an expert of wolfram mathematica, anyhow I decided to use it to perform analysis on some data I acquired. I found on this website a question about how to do peak deconvolution and I tried to use it. I think the result is quite ok in terms of shape, but I don't understand why the curves I found to fit my data are shifted. I want them to be plotted in the same graph as my original data, but somehow the axis are changed and are from 0 to 1 instead of their actual value.
I attached the code and the data below. In my data the x axis is supposed to be from 380 to 460, and the y axis is supposed to be from 0 to 0.5 more and less.
I can give more information if needed, thanks to anyone that can try to help me.
Francesca

EDIT:

The code is:

```
    data = {{381.565, 0.233341}, {381.649, 0.237568}, {381.733, 
  0.241812}, {381.815, 0.246048}, {381.896, 0.25028}, {381.979, 
  0.254531}, {382.063, 0.258775}, {382.145, 0.263014}, {382.226, 
  0.267237}, {382.312, 0.271479}, {382.396, 0.275705}, {382.478, 
  0.279918}, {382.561, 0.284118}, {382.643, 0.288295}, {382.727, 
  0.292453}, {382.811, 0.296595}, {382.895, 0.300705}, {382.975, 
  0.304767}, {383.058, 0.308815}, {383.14, 0.312814}, {383.221, 
  0.31679}, {383.306, 0.320743}, {383.388, 0.324644}, {383.473, 
  0.328505}, {383.558, 0.332333}, {383.638, 0.336103}, {383.722, 
  0.339824}, {383.803, 0.343479}, {383.887, 0.347072}, {383.971, 
  0.350617}, {384.054, 0.354087}, {384.138, 0.357489}, {384.218, 
  0.360822}, {384.303, 0.364095}, {384.384, 0.367281}, {384.468, 
  0.370411}, {384.548, 0.373447}, {384.633, 0.376413}, {384.716, 
  0.379297}, {384.8, 0.382099}, {384.883, 0.384808}, {384.965, 
  0.387416}, {385.048, 0.389932}, {385.132, 0.392354}, {385.214, 
  0.394668}, {385.298, 0.396889}, {385.379, 0.399007}, {385.465, 
  0.401039}, {385.547, 0.402964}, {385.625, 0.40478}, {385.713, 
  0.406509}, {385.796, 0.408149}, {385.878, 0.409683}, {385.96, 
  0.411111}, {386.042, 0.412438}, {386.127, 0.413683}, {386.211, 
  0.414828}, {386.291, 0.415885}, {386.374, 0.416868}, {386.46, 
  0.41776}, {386.541, 0.418547}, {386.624, 0.419249}, {386.706, 
  0.419851}, {386.789, 0.420369}, {386.873, 0.420809}, {386.955, 
  0.421159}, {387.039, 0.42144}, {387.121, 0.42163}, {387.205, 
  0.421728}, {387.287, 0.421769}, {387.367, 0.42173}, {387.451, 
  0.421623}, {387.532, 0.42145}, {387.617, 0.421204}, {387.702, 
  0.420889}, {387.783, 0.420509}, {387.867, 0.420047}, {387.954, 
  0.419511}, {388.035, 0.41892}, {388.116, 0.418272}, {388.201, 
  0.417545}, {388.281, 0.416782}, {388.365, 0.415949}, {388.449, 
  0.415059}, {388.53, 0.414108}, {388.614, 0.413095}, {388.694, 
  0.412031}, {388.777, 0.410916}, {388.863, 0.409764}, {388.944, 
  0.408564}, {389.027, 0.407314}, {389.111, 0.406008}, {389.193, 
  0.404657}, {389.276, 0.403278}, {389.359, 0.401851}, {389.441, 
  0.400387}, {389.525, 0.398874}, {389.611, 0.397334}, {389.691, 
  0.395744}, {389.773, 0.394116}, {389.855, 0.392452}, {389.94, 
  0.390757}, {390.024, 0.389038}, {390.105, 0.387304}, {390.191, 
  0.385539}, {390.272, 0.383751}, {390.355, 0.381928}, {390.437, 
  0.3801}, {390.518, 0.378259}, {390.603, 0.376382}, {390.69, 
  0.374521}, {390.769, 0.372635}, {390.85, 0.37074}, {390.935, 
  0.368835}, {391.02, 0.366917}, {391.1, 0.365017}, {391.184, 
  0.363108}, {391.266, 0.361192}, {391.348, 0.359283}, {391.43, 
  0.357381}, {391.515, 0.35548}, {391.596, 0.353584}, {391.682, 
  0.351689}, {391.765, 0.349806}, {391.845, 0.347938}, {391.931, 
  0.34607}, {392.013, 0.344228}, {392.096, 0.342384}, {392.182, 
  0.340566}, {392.262, 0.338768}, {392.346, 0.336973}, {392.429, 
  0.335224}, {392.511, 0.33349}, {392.594, 0.331787}, {392.677, 
  0.330111}, {392.756, 0.328461}, {392.84, 0.32683}, {392.923, 
  0.325238}, {393.007, 0.323651}, {393.088, 0.322094}, {393.176, 
  0.320558}, {393.254, 0.319063}, {393.337, 0.317605}, {393.421, 
  0.316176}, {393.506, 0.314766}, {393.591, 0.313391}, {393.676, 
  0.312046}, {393.756, 0.310742}, {393.836, 0.309481}, {393.92, 
  0.30824}, {394.003, 0.307037}, {394.088, 0.305866}, {394.169, 
  0.30473}, {394.249, 0.303632}, {394.332, 0.302552}, {394.416, 
  0.301506}, {394.501, 0.30049}, {394.58, 0.299504}, {394.666, 
  0.298536}, {394.749, 0.297603}, {394.832, 0.296704}, {394.915, 
  0.295847}, {394.999, 0.295028}, {395.08, 0.294228}, {395.161, 
  0.293456}, {395.245, 0.292699}, {395.329, 0.291963}, {395.412, 
  0.291263}, {395.494, 0.290585}, {395.58, 0.289941}, {395.66, 
  0.28933}, {395.746, 0.288722}, {395.828, 0.288147}, {395.908, 
  0.287605}, {395.993, 0.287085}, {396.074, 0.286571}, {396.157, 
  0.286076}, {396.241, 0.285601}, {396.324, 0.285144}, {396.407, 
  0.284706}, {396.49, 0.284295}, {396.574, 0.283904}, {396.655, 
  0.283526}, {396.739, 0.283162}, {396.824, 0.282812}, {396.904, 
  0.282489}, {396.986, 0.282178}, {397.072, 0.281882}, {397.155, 
  0.2816}, {397.237, 0.28132}, {397.321, 0.281057}, {397.402, 
  0.280803}, {397.484, 0.280561}, {397.569, 0.280334}, {397.653, 
  0.280124}, {397.734, 0.279924}, {397.816, 0.279734}, {397.897, 
  0.279556}, {397.981, 0.279383}, {398.064, 0.279207}, {398.148, 
  0.279049}, {398.23, 0.278892}, {398.313, 0.278745}, {398.396, 
  0.278602}, {398.479, 0.278466}, {398.561, 0.27833}, {398.646, 
  0.278205}, {398.731, 0.27808}, {398.811, 0.277968}, {398.893, 
  0.277864}, {398.976, 0.277768}, {399.06, 0.277673}, {399.142, 
  0.277582}, {399.222, 0.277485}, {399.309, 0.277401}, {399.39, 
  0.277311}, {399.472, 0.277224}, {399.558, 0.277149}, {399.641, 
  0.277082}, {399.724, 0.27702}, {399.808, 0.276961}, {399.89, 
  0.276906}, {399.969, 0.276845}, {400.052, 0.276782}, {400.137, 
  0.276731}, {400.221, 0.27669}, {400.306, 0.276644}, {400.386, 
  0.276599}, {400.47, 0.276548}, {400.553, 0.276512}, {400.634, 
  0.27647}, {400.718, 0.276433}, {400.8, 0.276399}, {400.883, 
  0.276368}, {400.964, 0.276352}, {401.048, 0.276324}, {401.133, 
  0.276293}, {401.215, 0.276268}, {401.297, 0.276248}, {401.381, 
  0.276217}, {401.465, 0.276185}, {401.544, 0.276162}, {401.631, 
  0.276144}, {401.712, 0.276131}, {401.796, 0.276128}, {401.878, 
  0.276119}, {401.96, 0.276109}, {402.043, 0.276108}, {402.127, 
  0.276095}, {402.209, 0.276076}, {402.291, 0.276065}, {402.374, 
  0.276048}, {402.458, 0.276031}, {402.541, 0.276011}, {402.624, 
  0.276003}, {402.705, 0.275983}, {402.79, 0.275977}, {402.872, 
  0.275966}, {402.955, 0.275963}, {403.039, 0.275967}, {403.124, 
  0.275964}, {403.203, 0.275952}, {403.288, 0.275946}, {403.371, 
  0.275943}, {403.453, 0.275941}, {403.535, 0.275938}, {403.616, 
  0.275935}, {403.699, 0.275922}, {403.783, 0.275904}, {403.869, 
  0.27589}, {403.948, 0.275875}, {404.034, 0.27586}, {404.114, 
  0.275841}, {404.2, 0.275825}, {404.28, 0.275826}, {404.365, 
  0.27582}, {404.451, 0.27581}, {404.531, 0.27581}, {404.615, 
  0.275806}, {404.696, 0.275802}, {404.779, 0.27579}, {404.86, 
  0.275773}, {404.945, 0.275751}, {405.03, 0.275745}, {405.112, 
  0.275745}, {405.191, 0.275739}, {405.277, 0.275724}, {405.357, 
  0.275709}, {405.442, 0.275693}, {405.524, 0.275668}, {405.608, 
  0.275639}, {405.69, 0.275624}, {405.774, 0.275599}, {405.858, 
  0.275581}, {405.939, 0.275558}, {406.024, 0.275539}, {406.107, 
  0.275521}, {406.188, 0.275498}, {406.269, 0.275472}, {406.354, 
  0.275447}, {406.438, 0.275418}, {406.521, 0.275387}, {406.604, 
  0.275366}, {406.687, 0.275335}, {406.768, 0.275304}, {406.851, 
  0.275274}, {406.933, 0.275245}, {407.015, 0.275219}, {407.098, 
  0.275193}, {407.182, 0.275164}, {407.264, 0.275139}, {407.348, 
  0.275114}, {407.429, 0.275087}, {407.517, 0.275054}, {407.596, 
  0.275015}, {407.682, 0.274974}, {407.763, 0.274944}, {407.845, 
  0.274906}, {407.929, 0.274864}, {408.012, 0.274825}, {408.094, 
  0.274783}, {408.179, 0.274729}, {408.259, 0.27468}, {408.342, 
  0.274634}, {408.425, 0.274579}, {408.509, 0.274524}, {408.59, 
  0.274469}, {408.675, 0.274409}, {408.758, 0.274345}, {408.839, 
  0.274291}, {408.922, 0.27423}, {409.004, 0.274178}, {409.09, 
  0.274121}, {409.173, 0.274069}, {409.255, 0.274008}, {409.336, 
  0.273948}, {409.42, 0.273882}, {409.502, 0.273807}, {409.584, 
  0.273737}, {409.666, 0.273675}, {409.753, 0.273612}, {409.835, 
  0.273542}, {409.918, 0.273491}, {409.999, 0.273428}, {410.081, 
  0.273357}, {410.166, 0.27329}, {410.251, 0.273231}, {410.331, 
  0.273156}, {410.414, 0.273088}, {410.498, 0.273014}, {410.582, 
  0.272937}, {410.663, 0.272863}, {410.75, 0.27278}, {410.829, 
  0.2727}, {410.913, 0.272619}, {410.995, 0.272546}, {411.078, 
  0.272468}, {411.158, 0.272386}, {411.242, 0.272309}, {411.327, 
  0.272229}, {411.412, 0.272144}, {411.492, 0.272059}, {411.575, 
  0.271968}, {411.657, 0.271876}, {411.739, 0.271788}, {411.822, 
  0.2717}, {411.905, 0.271613}, {411.987, 0.271525}, {412.07, 
  0.271437}, {412.157, 0.271344}, {412.237, 0.271246}, {412.319, 
  0.271151}, {412.403, 0.271054}, {412.486, 0.270957}, {412.569, 
  0.270853}, {412.652, 0.270755}, {412.734, 0.270646}, {412.818, 
  0.27054}, {412.902, 0.270433}, {412.982, 0.270312}, {413.065, 
  0.270206}, {413.149, 0.270105}, {413.233, 0.269993}, {413.315, 
  0.269886}, {413.4, 0.269784}, {413.485, 0.269685}, {413.564, 
  0.269585}, {413.645, 0.269486}, {413.73, 0.269384}, {413.81, 
  0.269274}, {413.894, 0.269158}, {413.977, 0.269045}, {414.059, 
  0.268938}, {414.143, 0.268819}, {414.226, 0.268698}, {414.31, 
  0.268577}, {414.394, 0.268455}, {414.476, 0.268323}, {414.559, 
  0.268203}, {414.64, 0.268077}, {414.722, 0.267966}, {414.809, 
  0.267849}, {414.887, 0.267735}, {414.973, 0.267614}, {415.058, 
  0.26749}, {415.137, 0.267369}, {415.218, 0.267254}, {415.304, 
  0.267135}, {415.387, 0.267017}, {415.469, 0.266909}, {415.555, 
  0.266795}, {415.634, 0.266669}, {415.718, 0.266543}, {415.801, 
  0.266422}, {415.884, 0.266297}, {415.967, 0.266176}, {416.05, 
  0.26605}, {416.134, 0.265927}, {416.213, 0.265805}, {416.3, 
  0.265682}, {416.381, 0.265561}, {416.462, 0.265427}, {416.547, 
  0.2653}, {416.63, 0.265175}, {416.709, 0.265053}, {416.795, 
  0.264924}, {416.878, 0.264793}, {416.961, 0.264661}, {417.044, 
  0.264535}, {417.127, 0.264416}, {417.212, 0.26429}, {417.292, 
  0.264166}, {417.375, 0.264044}, {417.46, 0.263919}, {417.541, 
  0.263799}, {417.623, 0.263671}, {417.708, 0.263541}, {417.79, 
  0.263415}, {417.87, 0.26329}, {417.958, 0.263156}, {418.038, 
  0.263019}, {418.118, 0.262883}, {418.204, 0.262746}, {418.286, 
  0.262609}, {418.369, 0.262472}, {418.451, 0.262329}, {418.535, 
  0.262186}, {418.619, 0.26205}, {418.699, 0.261922}, {418.782, 
  0.261783}, {418.866, 0.261648}, {418.951, 0.261516}, {419.031, 
  0.261381}, {419.115, 0.261252}, {419.198, 0.261123}, {419.279, 
  0.260988}, {419.364, 0.260865}, {419.449, 0.26073}, {419.527, 
  0.260602}, {419.612, 0.260471}, {419.693, 0.260346}, {419.777, 
  0.260229}, {419.86, 0.260099}, {419.943, 0.259984}, {420.027, 
  0.259865}, {420.109, 0.259741}, {420.192, 0.259624}, {420.273, 
  0.259507}, {420.356, 0.259378}, {420.437, 0.259249}, {420.521, 
  0.259115}, {420.605, 0.258978}, {420.692, 0.258851}, {420.769, 
  0.258719}, {420.854, 0.258584}, {420.936, 0.258451}, {421.022, 
  0.258328}, {421.103, 0.258198}, {421.186, 0.25806}, {421.269, 
  0.257931}, {421.348, 0.257804}, {421.435, 0.257678}, {421.517, 
  0.257553}, {421.599, 0.257433}, {421.681, 0.257307}, {421.766, 
  0.257185}, {421.849, 0.257061}, {421.932, 0.256937}, {422.014, 
  0.256818}, {422.097, 0.2567}, {422.179, 0.256581}, {422.262, 
  0.256455}, {422.345, 0.256332}, {422.429, 0.256213}, {422.512, 
  0.25609}, {422.596, 0.255966}, {422.677, 0.255847}, {422.76, 
  0.255723}, {422.842, 0.255597}, {422.924, 0.25548}, {423.009, 
  0.255348}, {423.092, 0.255219}, {423.176, 0.255096}, {423.256, 
  0.254971}, {423.34, 0.254837}, {423.425, 0.254706}, {423.506, 
  0.254579}, {423.59, 0.254458}, {423.67, 0.254337}, {423.754, 
  0.25421}, {423.837, 0.254096}, {423.918, 0.253975}, {424.003, 
  0.253848}, {424.085, 0.253729}, {424.168, 0.253615}, {424.254, 
  0.253498}, {424.33, 0.25338}, {424.416, 0.253258}, {424.499, 
  0.253131}, {424.581, 0.253012}, {424.665, 0.252885}, {424.748, 
  0.252767}, {424.834, 0.252644}, {424.915, 0.252517}, {424.997, 
  0.252396}, {425.08, 0.252273}, {425.16, 0.252147}, {425.244, 
  0.252021}, {425.327, 0.251905}, {425.409, 0.25179}, {425.495, 
  0.251683}, {425.577, 0.251576}, {425.658, 0.251463}, {425.741, 
  0.251335}, {425.824, 0.251234}, {425.909, 0.251127}, {425.988, 
  0.251023}, {426.073, 0.250908}, {426.156, 0.250795}, {426.239, 
  0.250689}, {426.322, 0.250582}, {426.403, 0.25048}, {426.488, 
  0.250363}, {426.571, 0.250246}, {426.653, 0.250127}, {426.737, 
  0.250017}, {426.821, 0.24991}, {426.902, 0.2498}, {426.982, 
  0.249685}, {427.066, 0.249566}, {427.147, 0.249448}, {427.232, 
  0.249336}, {427.315, 0.24922}, {427.399, 0.24911}, {427.481, 
  0.248994}, {427.564, 0.248881}, {427.647, 0.248757}, {427.729, 
  0.248638}, {427.812, 0.248518}, {427.894, 0.248401}, {427.979, 
  0.24828}, {428.061, 0.248159}, {428.145, 0.248039}, {428.224, 
  0.247919}, {428.31, 0.2478}, {428.392, 0.247682}, {428.476, 
  0.247554}, {428.559, 0.247426}, {428.641, 0.247297}, {428.727, 
  0.24718}, {428.806, 0.247062}, {428.89, 0.246933}, {428.97, 
  0.246803}, {429.055, 0.246673}, {429.138, 0.246544}, {429.219, 
  0.246423}, {429.303, 0.246287}, {429.387, 0.246161}, {429.469, 
  0.246036}, {429.55, 0.245906}, {429.637, 0.245776}, {429.717, 
  0.245648}, {429.8, 0.245525}, {429.885, 0.245397}, {429.966, 
  0.24527}, {430.049, 0.245138}, {430.131, 0.24501}, {430.215, 
  0.244886}, {430.297, 0.24476}, {430.381, 0.24463}, {430.463, 
  0.244498}, {430.545, 0.244355}, {430.629, 0.244207}, {430.71, 
  0.244057}, {430.792, 0.243906}, {430.875, 0.243752}, {430.959, 
  0.243592}, {431.044, 0.243441}, {431.126, 0.243289}, {431.209, 
  0.243133}, {431.292, 0.242972}, {431.372, 0.24281}, {431.454, 
  0.24265}, {431.536, 0.242485}, {431.621, 0.242323}, {431.705, 
  0.242155}, {431.786, 0.241985}, {431.869, 0.241814}, {431.952, 
  0.241634}, {432.036, 0.241459}, {432.12, 0.241283}, {432.202, 
  0.241109}, {432.287, 0.240929}, {432.368, 0.240748}, {432.45, 
  0.240565}, {432.529, 0.240382}, {432.617, 0.240202}, {432.698, 
  0.240012}, {432.781, 0.239828}, {432.863, 0.239635}, {432.947, 
  0.23944}, {433.028, 0.239237}, {433.111, 0.239039}, {433.193, 
  0.238831}, {433.277, 0.238629}, {433.359, 0.238425}, {433.443, 
  0.238217}, {433.526, 0.238007}, {433.61, 0.237784}, {433.691, 
  0.237561}, {433.773, 0.237329}, {433.857, 0.237091}, {433.94, 
  0.236848}, {434.024, 0.236606}, {434.107, 0.236353}, {434.187, 
  0.236104}, {434.271, 0.235861}, {434.352, 0.235613}, {434.433, 
  0.235357}, {434.519, 0.235097}, {434.603, 0.234841}, {434.688, 
  0.234576}, {434.769, 0.234304}, {434.852, 0.234034}, {434.932, 
  0.233753}, {435.017, 0.233464}, {435.099, 0.233175}, {435.182, 
  0.232873}, {435.266, 0.232565}, {435.347, 0.232263}, {435.429, 
  0.231956}, {435.513, 0.231656}, {435.594, 0.23136}, {435.676, 
  0.231055}, {435.761, 0.23073}, {435.845, 0.230407}, {435.927, 
  0.230094}, {436.01, 0.229778}, {436.095, 0.229455}, {436.178, 
  0.229121}, {436.261, 0.228778}, {436.342, 0.228428}, {436.424, 
  0.22808}, {436.507, 0.227725}, {436.588, 0.227364}, {436.671, 
  0.226991}, {436.754, 0.22661}, {436.836, 0.226226}, {436.922, 
  0.225845}, {437.004, 0.225455}, {437.089, 0.225058}, {437.169, 
  0.224662}, {437.253, 0.224262}, {437.335, 0.223854}, {437.418, 
  0.223441}, {437.502, 0.223023}, {437.581, 0.222612}, {437.668, 
  0.222184}, {437.746, 0.221746}, {437.83, 0.221301}, {437.914, 
  0.220852}, {437.999, 0.220383}, {438.078, 0.219913}, {438.163, 
  0.219436}, {438.247, 0.218953}, {438.328, 0.218469}, {438.411, 
  0.217977}, {438.492, 0.217482}, {438.577, 0.216989}, {438.661, 
  0.216487}, {438.742, 0.215981}, {438.824, 0.215475}, {438.909, 
  0.214956}, {438.99, 0.21442}, {439.074, 0.213874}, {439.157, 
  0.213318}, {439.24, 0.212765}, {439.324, 0.212203}, {439.405, 
  0.211633}, {439.486, 0.211064}, {439.569, 0.21048}, {439.65, 
  0.20989}, {439.737, 0.209286}, {439.819, 0.208683}, {439.902, 
  0.208074}, {439.986, 0.207458}, {440.067, 0.206829}, {440.152, 
  0.206195}, {440.235, 0.20556}, {440.314, 0.204919}, {440.399, 
  0.204269}, {440.481, 0.203616}, {440.561, 0.202952}, {440.647, 
  0.202278}, {440.729, 0.201607}, {440.812, 0.200922}, {440.895, 
  0.200227}, {440.976, 0.19952}, {441.059, 0.198807}, {441.141, 
  0.198089}, {441.224, 0.197368}, {441.309, 0.196636}, {441.394, 
  0.195893}, {441.476, 0.195149}, {441.557, 0.194399}, {441.641, 
  0.193646}, {441.722, 0.192886}, {441.806, 0.192108}, {441.888, 
  0.191325}, {441.973, 0.190532}, {442.057, 0.189735}, {442.138, 
  0.188932}, {442.22, 0.188127}, {442.301, 0.187315}, {442.385, 
  0.186491}, {442.468, 0.185665}, {442.55, 0.184824}, {442.632, 
  0.183983}, {442.717, 0.183129}, {442.8, 0.182271}, {442.878, 
  0.181415}, {442.966, 0.180551}, {443.049, 0.179681}, {443.129, 
  0.178809}, {443.215, 0.177927}, {443.295, 0.177045}, {443.378, 
  0.176164}, {443.462, 0.175282}, {443.543, 0.174404}, {443.627, 
  0.173525}, {443.711, 0.172642}, {443.792, 0.171757}, {443.875, 
  0.17087}, {443.959, 0.169981}, {444.04, 0.169095}, {444.126, 
  0.168207}, {444.205, 0.16732}, {444.288, 0.16644}, {444.371, 
  0.16556}, {444.453, 0.164683}, {444.538, 0.163806}, {444.621, 
  0.162933}, {444.706, 0.162067}, {444.786, 0.161206}, {444.87, 
  0.160345}, {444.952, 0.159488}, {445.036, 0.158632}, {445.118, 
  0.157783}, {445.199, 0.156938}, {445.282, 0.156089}, {445.366, 
  0.155246}, {445.448, 0.15441}, {445.533, 0.153576}, {445.617, 
  0.152752}, {445.694, 0.151938}, {445.779, 0.151127}, {445.861, 
  0.150319}, {445.946, 0.149517}, {446.027, 0.148724}, {446.11, 
  0.147934}, {446.192, 0.147152}, {446.274, 0.146372}, {446.361, 
  0.145588}, {446.444, 0.144811}, {446.526, 0.144039}, {446.608, 
  0.143275}, {446.69, 0.142515}, {446.772, 0.141761}, {446.857, 
  0.14101}, {446.94, 0.140264}, {447.021, 0.139524}, {447.105, 
  0.138783}, {447.186, 0.138049}, {447.27, 0.13732}, {447.352, 
  0.136596}, {447.434, 0.135877}, {447.519, 0.13516}, {447.602, 
  0.134455}, {447.685, 0.133762}, {447.768, 0.133068}, {447.849, 
  0.132377}, {447.932, 0.13169}, {448.012, 0.131004}, {448.096, 
  0.130317}, {448.181, 0.129636}, {448.263, 0.128956}, {448.346, 
  0.12828}, {448.426, 0.127607}, {448.511, 0.126928}, {448.592, 
  0.126261}, {448.673, 0.125603}, {448.758, 0.124947}, {448.842, 
  0.124295}, {448.925, 0.12365}, {449.008, 0.123003}, {449.09, 
  0.12236}, {449.175, 0.121713}, {449.254, 0.121073}, {449.339, 
  0.120436}, {449.421, 0.119803}, {449.505, 0.119173}, {449.587, 
  0.118541}, {449.671, 0.11791}, {449.751, 0.117281}, {449.834, 
  0.116651}, {449.919, 0.116021}, {449.999, 0.115395}, {450.084, 
  0.114761}, {450.166, 0.114131}, {450.248, 0.1135}, {450.332, 
  0.112872}, {450.412, 0.112246}, {450.496, 0.111616}, {450.582, 
  0.110987}, {450.664, 0.110355}, {450.744, 0.109729}, {450.828, 
  0.109102}, {450.912, 0.108473}, {450.992, 0.107843}, {451.076, 
  0.107207}, {451.158, 0.106568}, {451.241, 0.105926}, {451.328, 
  0.105282}, {451.409, 0.104637}, {451.492, 0.103989}, {451.572, 
  0.10334}, {451.654, 0.102691}, {451.739, 0.102038}, {451.819, 
  0.101385}, {451.905, 0.100724}, {451.989, 0.100058}, {452.071, 
  0.0993886}, {452.153, 0.0987159}, {452.235, 0.0980404}, {452.319, 
  0.0973631}, {452.402, 0.0966794}, {452.486, 0.0959935}, {452.568, 
  0.0953034}, {452.647, 0.0946087}, {452.731, 0.0939053}, {452.813, 
  0.093197}, {452.897, 0.0924834}, {452.982, 0.091761}, {453.062, 
  0.0910375}, {453.144, 0.0903094}, {453.228, 0.0895738}, {453.311, 
  0.0888354}, {453.393, 0.0880939}, {453.476, 0.0873507}, {453.559, 
  0.0866047}, {453.643, 0.085854}, {453.725, 0.0851032}, {453.809, 
  0.0843488}, {453.893, 0.0835931}, {453.974, 0.0828367}, {454.056, 
  0.0820766}, {454.139, 0.0813187}, {454.222, 0.0805568}, {454.303, 
  0.079797}, {454.385, 0.0790357}, {454.468, 0.0782754}, {454.554, 
  0.0775137}, {454.636, 0.0767557}, {454.717, 0.0759977}, {454.801, 
  0.0752398}, {454.886, 0.0744844}, {454.966, 0.0737317}, {455.05, 
  0.072978}, {455.13, 0.0722292}, {455.215, 0.0714793}, {455.297, 
  0.0707337}, {455.379, 0.0699885}, {455.464, 0.0692452}, {455.545, 
  0.0685093}, {455.629, 0.0677725}, {455.708, 0.0670408}, {455.791, 
  0.0663102}, {455.877, 0.0655807}, {455.959, 0.0648556}, {456.041, 
  0.0641358}, {456.125, 0.0634179}, {456.208, 0.0627041}, {456.292, 
  0.061996}, {456.374, 0.0612902}, {456.455, 0.0605878}, {456.538, 
  0.0598894}, {456.619, 0.0591969}, {456.705, 0.0585065}, {456.787, 
  0.0578216}, {456.868, 0.0571436}, {456.951, 0.0564693}, {457.037, 
  0.0557971}, {457.118, 0.0551307}, {457.201, 0.0544693}, {457.284, 
  0.0538127}, {457.368, 0.0531611}, {457.447, 0.0525162}, {457.531, 
  0.0518733}, {457.613, 0.0512354}, {457.696, 0.0506028}, {457.779, 
  0.0499768}, {457.86, 0.0493575}, {457.946, 0.0487412}, {458.028, 
  0.048131}, {458.111, 0.0475262}, {458.194, 0.0469275}, {458.277, 
  0.0463353}, {458.359, 0.0457466}, {458.441, 0.0451644}, {458.523, 
  0.044588}, {458.606, 0.0440172}, {458.691, 0.0434511}, {458.775, 
  0.0428909}, {458.854, 0.0423388}, {458.937, 0.0417886}, {459.024, 
  0.0412415}, {459.102, 0.0407048}, {459.187, 0.0401716}, {459.268, 
  0.039645}, {459.353, 0.0391233}, {459.435, 0.0386088}, {459.518, 
  0.0381006}, {459.599, 0.0375987}, {459.681, 0.0371}, {459.766, 
  0.036607}, {459.848, 0.0361225}, {459.93, 0.0356414}, {460.015, 
  0.0351666}, {460.096, 0.0346993}, {460.179, 0.0342358}, {460.263, 
  0.0337773}}

    data1 = Rest@Transpose[Rescale /@ (Transpose@data)];
peakfunc[A_, \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_, x_] = 
  A^2 E^(-((x - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)));

Clear[model, modelvalue]
model[data_, n_] := 
 Module[{dataconfig, modelfunc, objfunc, fitvar, fitres}, 
  dataconfig = {A[#], \[Mu][#], \[Sigma][#]} & /@ Range[n];
  modelfunc = (peakfunc[##, fitvar] & @@@ dataconfig // Total);
  objfunc = 
   Total[((Sqrt[data[[All, 2]]])/
       data[[All, 
        1]]) (data[[All, 2]] - (modelfunc /. fitvar -> # &) /@ 
         data[[All, 1]])^2];
  FindMinimum[objfunc, Join[{}, Flatten@dataconfig]]]
modelvalue[data_, n_] /; NumericQ[n] := 
 If[n >= 1, model[data, n][[1]], 0]
fitres = ReleaseHold[
   Hold[{Round[n], model[data1, Round[n]]}] /. 
    FindMinimum[modelvalue[data1, Round[n]], {n, 5}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalAxis"][[2]]] // Quiet

With[{n = 3}, 
 resfunc = 
  peakfunc[A[#], \[Mu][#], \[Sigma][#], x] & /@ Range[n] /. 
   model[data1, n][[2]]]

Show@{Plot[Evaluate[resfunc], {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> ({Directive[Dashed, Thick, 
         ColorData["Rainbow"][#]]} & /@ 
      Rescale[Range[Length[resfunc]]]), PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Total@resfunc], {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.003], Black, Point@data1}]}
```

Comment: Please post code as text, rather than images - nobody wants to type out all that code. It looks like you `Rescale` the data right at the beginning, which is probably what's causing that behaviour.

Comment: I believe `Show` follows the `PlotRange` of the first plot listed.  Looks like you are specifying `{x,0,1}` which is causing the x-range to be just that.

Comment: I think you are right @CarlLange and thanks so much for your help (I know posting the code is better, but I had some issues with attaching it to my comment). Kind Regards

Comment: @mjw it's not much a problem of how it's plotted, it's the functions themselves that are in a different range than the original one. Thank you for trying to help anyway.

Comment: @Francesca There are two things you should do: 1) include your code as text rather than as a picture: that way we can copy and past it into MMA and play with it ourselves. 2) include the data you are trying to fit in your question, or by linking to a pastebin (e.g. pastebin.com).

Comment: I just posted my code as text and not as a picture. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: "I found on this website a question about how to do peak deconvolution and I tried to use it." Please post a link to this question.

Comment: @C.E. I am really sorry but I don't know which question it was anymore, it was a while ago, and before posting this question I tried to solve the issues I had with peak deconvolution on my own. Anyway the code I posted is exactly the one I found in one of the answers related to peak deconvolution.